# Set webrowser control url to embedded html file?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to set a webbrowser control URL to an HTML file named "HomeHTML.html" that is embedded into the application. I can't figure out how to target it to set the new URL.

```
webbrowser.Url = new Uri(HomeHTML.html); //dosen't work
```

Comment: You can use either of the following options: Copy the file somewhere like temp directory or application folder, then set the file path as URL of the web browser control. You also can set `DocumentText` property of the web browser control, to the content of the embedded html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, if anyone else has the same problem this code will work.

```
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory"home.html");
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(filepath);
```